# Java-Working of Recursion without any return statement?

Tags: java, recursion

Please explain working of the recursive method? 
 that means working of the call stack

```
class rec
{
    public static void func(int i)
    {
        if (i>=1)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            func(i-1);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        func(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: That's some pretty simple code. You need to read a Java tutorial if you can't understand such a simple example.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger and you will be able to see what each line of code does.  I also suggest you use your IDE's code formatter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is that edit supposed to improve the formatting?

Comment: In this case, the println statements help you see how the method is working.  I would run this code and see what it does and see if you can work out what it is doing.

Comment: @bcsb1001 The OP missed a blank line at the start so SO wasn't formatting a lot of it as code. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9406142

Comment: Looks like the brackets are in a mess...

Comment: @user3437460 it's also pseudo Java code. ;)

Comment: The brackets looks much better now!

Comment: how does this code work? Just run that program and see how it works!! Further, if you have any question on why something behaves like something, post it

Comment: @Simz- its a rough code just to get a idea of problem

Comment: output is:- 5432112345. I want to know how? as function is not returning any value?

Comment: @PeterLawrey now, i think question is clear.

Comment: @A.Pan A good way to get an idea is to write code which runs and actually run it.

Comment: @A.Pan the question for me is; What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @PeterLawrey output  of above program is:-
5
4
3
2
1
1
2
3
4
5
how  as function's return type is void? Howz the call stack working?

Comment: @A.Pan: Why would something need a `return` statement to be recursive?

Comment: @David  okay, so what it means is that there is a stack...which contain state of recursion. I mean when func(0) is executed nothing happens i.e. end of recursion. so it unwinds the  stack.

Comment: @A.Pan: Do you understand what recursion is and how it works?  The function calls itself, adding another frame of the function to the stack.  This continues until one of the functions *doesn't* call itself, at which point all of the functions begin returning back up the stack.

Comment: @A.Pan from reading the output, you might conclude the function returns when it reaches the end of the code. This is what it actually does.

Comment: @David what I asked is why are functions returning back up the stack?

Comment: @A.Pan you can see it doesn't unwind the whole stack.  You can see that after func(0) it still prints `1 2 3 4 5` There is one `return` and it returns once.

Comment: @A.Pan what would you expect them to do instead?

Comment: @A.Pan: What else would you expect to happen when a function finishes executing?

Comment: @A.Pan If you are given a list of instructions to do something.  What do you do when you run out of instructions? Perhaps you might go back to whomever gave you the instruction for more, or continue what you were doing.

Comment: thnk u...now I understand that there is still going back to the point of calling.
i.e. return;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This recursion can run without going into a infinite "looping" because you `i` value decreases in every recursive call - A bigger problem broken down into smaller one until it is finally solved.

First you pass in 5, it fulfils the condition, make another recursive call:

```
func(5) --> func(4)
```

You pass in 4, it fulfils the condition, make another recursive call and so on:

```
func(5) --> func(4) --> func(3) --> func(2) --> func(1)
```

When a method completes its task, it **return to the point of calling**, thus you start popping out from the stack.

```
print(1) --> print(2) --> print(3) --> print(4) --> print(5) --> back to main().
```

If you correct your errors, your are able to run and it will produce the following results:

```
5
4
3
2
1
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

**Reply for your comments:** It can display `5432112345` because you did `System.out.println` within the method! You don't need to return a value to be able to print those numbers.

Comment: okay...so that's the concept that is popping the stack. when func(1) is completely executed ...it's popped from the stack and then func(2) is executed and so on. right? THnx.

Comment: @A.Pan No, in this case all 5 will not pop until it reaches the last recursive call. After the last recursive method finishes its task, it starts to pop.

Comment: @A.Pan So remember who called func(1)? func(2) called it right? So it will return to the point of calling which is func(2). func(2) also finished its task, so return to point of calling: func(3). By then func(3) also finished its task, hence return to point of calling: func(4)..and so on till everything is popped from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I made a Flow Chart for you so that you understand it well ! , I gave input 4 .

here is all of the code , but you have to know that at last there is a return statement , if you don't write return , it is totally ok just that you understand it well .

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    func(3);
}

public static void func(int i) {
    if (i >= 1) {
        System.out.println(i);
        func(i - 1);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    return;
}
```